# Unable to Pickle ldap3 datetime object with tzinfo attribute

Tags: python, pickle, python-datetime, ldap3

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
import pickle

server = Server('ipa.demo1.freeipa.org', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, 'uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org', 'Secret123', auto_bind=True)
entries = conn.extend.standard.paged_search('dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org', '(objectClass=person)', attributes=['cn', 'givenName', 'createtimestamp'], paged_size=5)

testlist = []

for entry in entries:
    testlist.append(entry)

output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(testlist, output)
output.close()

pkl_file = open('data.pkl', 'rb')
test2 = pickle.load(pkl_file)

pkl_file.close()
```

gives...

```
C:\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/xxxxx/Dropbox/xxx/Work/Python/CEDAR/ldaptest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxxx/Dropbox/xxx/Work/Python/CEDAR/ldaptest.py", line 20, in <module>
    test2 = pickle.load(pkl_file)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'offset' and 'name'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

this looks to be related to [ldap3.core.timezone.py...](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/blob/master/ldap3/core/timezone.py)

the `createtimestamp` attribute looks to be `datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 18, 11, 13, 38, tzinfo=OffsetTzInfo(offset=0, name='UTC'))`

unfortunately this is where I don't have a clue what to do next...  Is this something that should be addressed before pickling with the datetime object itself?

I'm not able to re-create this with a regular Python datetime object.

Comment: Try to import `tzinfo` in your `__main__` Namespace. If this doesn't help you have to remove `tzinfo` from `createtimestamp` before picking and reassing it after depickelinf.

Comment: I believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36238351/python-pickle-loads-failed-for-class-instance to be related